# how each tree in random forest structured/built?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, supervised-learning

I'm new to machine learning and I want to use random forest for the problem I have. What I have done so far is I did the 80/20 split of the original data set.

I need to understand what will happen next when building the random forest model. I understand that the next step is taking a random sample (with replacement) from the 80% portion used for training, and use this bootstrapped data set to build a decision tree. Let's assume I have 5 features/columns, and to select a root node, a random subset of the 5 features are selected, and the variable that has the highest `Gini index` is the root.Let us assume feature 2 is the root.

Next, a random subset of the remaining 4 features are selected to create child nodes for the root node. Let's assume feature 1 and 5 are selected.

My questions are:

1- after obtaining `Gini index` for feature 1 and 5 and let's assume node 1 has the higher index value, how do I know if node 1 should be the left or right node?

2- does node 5 become the left/right node now? or do we selected a random subset of the remaining 3 features (3, 4, 5), find their `Gini index` values and the right child becomes the node with the highest `Gini index`?

Comment: Do you want to implement random forests by your own or are you just aiming to gain a deeper understanding?

Comment: I'm trying to gain a deeper understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great questions! I'll do my best to answer them:

1. Once you have selected `feature 2` as the **root** and `features 1 and 5` as the **candidates** for the **first split**, you need to **determine** whether `node 1` should be the **left or right node**. To make this decision, you will **split the data** based on the values of `feature 2`. Any data points with a `feature 2` value **less than or equal** to the *threshold value* for `node 1` will be **assigned to the left node**, and any data points with `feature 2` value **greater than** the *threshold value* will be **assigned to the right node**. Once the data is split, you can calculate the **Gini index** for **each child node** using the **remaining features**.
2. `Node 5` is *not automatically assigned* to the **left or right node** after `node 1` is determined. Instead, you will select a **new random subset of the remaining 3 features** `(3, 4, 5)` to create **child nodes** for `node 1`. You will repeat the same process as before:

   - Calculate the **Gini index** for each candidate feature.
   - Select the feature with the **highest Gini index** as the **next node**
   - Split the data based on the threshold value of that node.
   - Then, you can calculate the **Gini index** for **each child node** using the remaining features.

You will ***continue this process recursively until you reach a stopping criterion***, such as a `maximum depth of the tree` or a `minimum number of samples per leaf node`. **Each decision tree** in the random forest will be **trained on a bootstrapped sample** of the training data. The final prediction will be the mode **(for classification) or mean (for regression)** of the predictions from **all the trees in the forest**.